# HTML в страницу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование, dom

Есть строка с html кодом, к примеру `<div><p>Example text</p></div>`. Как вставить её в код страницы? Код, что нужно вставить каждый раз меняться. Вроде бы можно через JQuery, но как не помню :(
Код должен вставляться в конец страницы

Comment: Куда вставить? Как меняться будет? Откуда вставить? Опишите ситуацию подробнее с примером.

Comment: Код должен вставляться в конец страницы

Comment: Что этому предшествует? Какие события? Вставляться прям в текст кода? Или должен создаваться DOM-элемент новый?

Comment: Новый DOM-элемент

Answer (score 1):

Тогда примерно так.

```js
const app = document.getElementById('app');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  const p = document.createElement('p');
  
  p.textContent = 'Newly created p in div';
  p.classList.add('new-p');
  div.classList.add('new-div');
  div.appendChild(p);
  app.appendChild(div);
});
```

```css
#app {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#btn {
  margin: 15px;
}

.new-div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}

.new-p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button id="btn">Create new div</button>
</div>
```